# CS-121 snmp adapter задержка

Tags: ubuntu, snmp

Есть UPS AEG Protect 3.M с SNMP адаптером CS-121. Проблема в долгом ответе на SNMP запросы, их около 20 штук. Задержка около 5-6 секунд. В чем может быть причина? И также долго отрабатывает SNMPWALK (более 10 секунд).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам адаптер не справляется с запросами, помогло уменьшение запросов до 5 штук.